# Opencart mcrypt_create_iv error after account transfer with cPanel

Tags: php, opencart, mcrypt

I transferred my hosting account on a new server with cPanel. After that, Opencart started to give this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv() in /home/arkadas/public_html/system/library/encryption.php on line 8

I installed `mcrypt` on my new server but it is still same. I checked all opencart forums but couldn't find any solutions for this.

Comment: Did you reload PHP? Did you enable the mcrypt module in the appropriate php.ini ?

Comment: You can create a **info.php** file with this line of code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, upload  it to your server to see if mcrypt is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only possible cause of such an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv()` is that `mcrypt` PHP extension is either 1. not loaded or 2. not installed at all.

Things to do:

1. make sure the `mcrypt` is installed on the server - if not, install it if possible (if not, ask Your provider to install it for You).
2. if yes or after installing make sure it is loaded by PHP in `php.ini` - remove the leading semicolon `;` from the line `;extension=mcrypt...`

On Debian system (Debian, (K|U|X)buntu) You can install it using this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```